Equivalence of omniscience principles for natural numbers and analytic omniscience principles for Cauchy real numbers
In constructive mathematics, a proposition $P$ is decidable if $P \vee \neg P$, and a proposition is stable if $\neg \neg P \implies P$. We have the following principles of omniscience for the natural numbers: Given any decidable predicates $\phi$ and $\psi$ on the natural numbers; i.e. one such that for all natural numbers $n$, $\phi(n)$ or $\neg \phi(n)$, and $\psi(n)$ or $\neg \psi(n)$

The limited principle of omniscience ($\mathrm{LPO}_\mathbb{N}$) for the natural numbers state that the existential quantifier $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}.\phi(n)$ is decidable

The weak limited principle of omniscience for the natural numbers ($\mathrm{WLPO}_\mathbb{N}$) state that the universal quantifier $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}.\phi(n)$ is decidable

Markov's principle for the natural numbers ($\mathrm{MP}_\mathbb{N}$) state that the existential quantifier $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}.\phi(n)$ is stable

The lesser limited principle of omniscience ($\mathrm{LLPO}_\mathbb{N}$) for the natural numbers states that if it is not the case that both existential quantifiers $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}.\phi(n)$ and $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}.\psi(n)$ hold, than either $\neg \exists n \in \mathbb{N}.\phi(n)$ or $\neg \exists n \in \mathbb{N}.\psi(n)$.


There are also the following analytic principles of omniscience for the Cauchy real numbers (i.e. equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers with modulus of convergence):

The analytic limited principle of omniscience for Cauchy real numbers state that the Cauchy real numbers have decidable apartness.

The analytic weak limited principle of omniscience for Cauchy real numbers state that the Cauchy real numbers have decidable equality.

The analytic Markov's principle for Cauchy real numbers state that the Cauchy real numbers have stable apartness.

The analytic lesser limited principle of omniscience for Cauchy real numbers state that the partial order on the Cauchy real numbers defined by the negation of the strict order $\lt$ is a total order.


Are the two sets of omniscience principles equivalent to each other? i.e.

Is $\mathrm{LPO}_\mathbb{N}$ equivalent to analytic LPO for Cauchy real numbers?

Is $\mathrm{WLPO}_\mathbb{N}$ equivalent to analytic WLPO for Cauchy real numbers?

Is $\mathrm{MP}_\mathbb{N}$ equivalent to analytic Markov's principle for Cauchy real numbers?

Is $\mathrm{LLPO}_\mathbb{N}$ equivalent to analytic LLPO for Cauchy real numbers?



Do we have countable choice? If not, why are we using Cauchy reals?

By a “Cauchy sequence” $(u_n)$, do you mean a Cauchy-with-modulus sequence $∃μ:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}.∀k.∀p,q≥μ(k).|u_p-u_q|<2^{-k}$ or a Cauchy-without-modulus sequence $∀k.∃n.∀p,q≥n.|u_p-u_q|<2^{-k}$ ?  Both have been called “Cauchy sequence”, so it would really be best to avoid the term without clarifying it as “with modulus” or “without modulus”.

@Gro-Tsen These Cauchy sequences come with a modulus as that is the convention in constructive mathematics when constructing the Cauchy real numbers as far as I am aware. I have edited the question to clarify that.

@AndrejBauer We do not have countable choice here. We are using the Cauchy real numbers here because that is what Toby Bartels was talking about in 2012 when he wrote on the nLab "In any case, if we use the Cauchy real numbers (sequential real numbers), then the sequential analytic (L)LPO is the same as the (L)LPO for natural numbers." but he did not provide a proof or reference for that statement.

As for Markov's principle, Toby Bartels made a similar claim on the nLab in 2011 when he wrote on the nLab "Equivalent forms: ... If a Cauchy real number does not equal zero, then it is apart from zero in that it has a multiplicative inverse." but didn't provide a proof or reference for that either.

Thank you for the clarification. For the record, as evidence that it is not so standard to assume (in the absence of Choice) that Cauchy sequences have a modulus of convergence, I can point to this paper (which explicitly says “Cauchy sequence with modulus” when it assumes one) and that one (which speaks of “regular reals” for the ones defined by a Cauchy sequence with modulus, and “Cauchy reals” for the ones without). So I think it's best to always clarify.

Note that the "property for Cauchy real implies property for natural numbers" direction is given by using the principles on Cantor set (whose elements are all Cauchy reals).

Let me try to tackle the LPO case.  I will even try to show that it doesn't matter whether we assume our Cauchy sequences to have a modulus or not.  (Please check me carefully because I know I've made mistakes on similar questions before.)
The easy direction is to prove that LPO for Cauchy reals (with or without modulus) implies LPO for natural numbers.  To this effect, let $b\colon\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ and we wish to show that either $\exists n.(b(n)=1)$ or that $\forall n.(b(n)=0)$.  Define $u_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ as $\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{-k}\,b(k)$.  Clearly this is Cauchy-with-explicit-modulus, so it defines a real $x$ (viꝫ. the limit of $(u_n)$): by LPO on the Cauchy reals (with or a fortiori without modulus), we have either $x\mathrel{\#}0$ (“is apart from”) or $x=0$.  In the former case, $x>2^{-k}$ for some $k$ so it is easy to see that some $b(n)=1$, and in the latter case, clearly $b(n)=0$ for all $n$. ∎
Now for the other direction.  We assume LPO for natural numbers.  Let $x$ be a Cauchy real, defined as the limit of a sequence $(u_n)$ of rationals, which we do not assume to have a modulus so as to have the most general result.  We want to show that $x\mathrel{\#}0$ or that $x=0$.  For notational convenience, we assume w.l.o.g. (replacing $u_n$ by $|u_n|$ and $x$ by $|x|$) that $u_n\geq 0$ and $x\geq 0$, so now we want to show that $x>0$ or that $x=0$.
Let $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$.  By LPO for the natural numbers (and because comparisons of rationals are decidable), either $u_m > 2^{-k}$ for some $m\geq n$ or $u_m \leq 2^{-k}$ for all $m\geq n$.  Since these two cases are exclusive, we can define $b(k,n)=1$ in the former and $b(k,n)=0$ in the latter.
Now let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ (but allow $n$ to vary).  By a second application of LPO on the natural numbers, either there is $n$ such that $b(k,n)=0$ or we have $b(k,n)=1$ for all $n$.  Again, these two cases are exclusive, so we can define $b(k)=0$ in the former and $b(k)=1$ in the latter.
Now by a third application of LPO on the natural numbers, either there is $k$ such that $b(k)=1$ or we have $b(k)=0$ for all $k$.
This shows that either $\exists k. \forall n. \exists m\geq n. (u_m > 2^{-k})$ or $\forall k. \exists n. \forall m\geq n. (u_m \leq 2^{-k})$.  In the former case we have $x\geq 2^{-k}$ so $x>0$.  In the latter case, we have $x=0$. ∎
PS [added in edit]: in the above, I wanted to show that LPO for natural numbers implies LPO for Cauchy reals even without modulus; but since the question was about Cauchy reals with modulus, I should point out that the proof (of the second part) simplifies: if we assume $|u_p-u_q|\leq 2^{-n}$ when $p,q\geq n$, then $x>0$ is equivalent to $\exists n.(u_n>2^{-n})$ and $x=0$ to $\forall n.(u_n\leq 2^{-n})$, so we need to show that either the former or the latter holds, and that is a single application of LPO for $\mathbb{N}$.
